# Registering collectionView inside UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In storyboard I created a UIViewController and added a collectionView inside it. I don't know why my cells aren't showing up.

```
class ImageCollectionView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let imageCellId = "imageCell"

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: imageCellId, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    return cell
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: `...UICollectionView(frame: .zero...)` At some point you want to give it a visible frame? You are overriding your IBOutlet, and I don't know why.

Comment: @Larme And add it to the view hierarchy.

Comment: @rmaddy Indeed, but I just saw afterwards (and edited my comment meanwhile), that's it's an `IBOulet`, so it's just erasing the ref to the one visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this

```
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

as you add the collectionView in IB

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

then don't reCreate it , as it's loaded with it's registered cell

---

If the connection doesn't go as it should then

```
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame:self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

and you'll have to register the cell programmatically , or use `UICollectionViewController`

---

**Edit:** in `AppDelegate`

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcID")
window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: When I delete that, I get "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" though.

Comment: @KennyHo Then connect the CollectionView in the Storyboard/Xib.

Comment: do you add the collection in IB ? , if not then assign a frame , if yes then comment this above line

Comment: Yea Its already connected but still getting that same error. Yes it's added in IB

Comment: then comment the mentioned line , and attach the error

Comment: I just added an image of what's going on

Comment: ok select the collection in IB , re drag it again to the swift file

Comment: If it doesn't work, how do you show/init your ViewController?

Comment: In AppDelegate, I show the viewController by setting window?.rootViewController = ImageCollectionView()  within applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: wow. Thank you so much! I've always programmed programmatically but trying to learn building with a mixture of both storyboard and programmatic. remembering to do that always messes me up. Thank you so much again!